# ESXi 6 (U02) connect to LAN (Windows VM ok, Centos is not)

Tags: networking, centos, vmware-esxi

I have strange network issue with ESXi 6.0 U2 intallation on DELL R720 server with 4 nics.

I used vmnic0 for installation and networking is fine (can access network, ping, etc.. subnet 172.16.x.x/24).

I used vmnic1 and create vswitch1 for LAN accesses (which in different subnet 10.x.x.x/24). I  also created a vmkernel adapter (management purpose) in this switch and assigned an IP address.

Both vmnic0 and vmnic1 are connected to different physical switches.

Then I install fresh Centos 7 and Windows 2012r2 VMs and attach to vswitch1. I also assigned all static IP for these VMs (subnet 10.x.x.x/24)

However, I have strange issue in LAN (10.x.x.x):

- From Esxi host, I cannot ping gateway in LAN (10.x.x.x)
- From Centos VM, I cannot ping gateway in LAN
- From Windows VM, I CAN ping to gateway in LAN
- Centos VM, Windows VM and Esxi host can ping each other.

I could not figure out what causes this problem. I tried change IP, MAC address but only Windows VM can access LAN without any problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: more info, what version of cent 7, what hardware version, output of `ip addr`, which nic (vmnic), does the switch see the cent7 mac via arp

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something is missing on your Linux VM IP config. Does your switch have a management IP? If so, is it on the same 10.x.x.x network? If so, can you ping it?

Could you run this command:

```
netstat -r
```

What is the exact ping error it gives you?